# Export csv file to user desktop for deployment

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this application I built. It is working fine and everything but the one thing am having trouble is to save my exported csv file to a user's desktop. To elaborate: I would usually hard code the path where the file is to be exported but in the case of deployment this wouldn't be feasible as that would mean changing the path each time for a user's machine. How do I make the exported path save to the desktop by default for all users? Below is my code

```
private void button6_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox5.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot export unless table name is specified!");
        }
        else
        {
            int count_row = dataGridView1.RowCount;
            int count_cell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;


            string path = "C:\\Users\\Jevon\\Desktop\\" + comboBox5.Text + ".csv";
            string rxHeader = "Code" + "," + "Description" + "," + "NDC" + "," + "Supplier Code"
            + "," + "Supplier Description" + "," + "Pack Size" + "," + "UOM" + Environment.NewLine;


            MessageBox.Show("Please wait while " + comboBox5.Text + " table is being exported..");

            for (int row_index = 0; row_index <= count_row - 2; row_index++)
            {

                for (int cell_index = 1; cell_index <= count_cell - 1; cell_index++)
                {
                    textBox8.Text = textBox8.Text + dataGridView1.Rows[row_index].Cells[cell_index].Value.ToString() + ",";

                }
                textBox8.Text = textBox8.Text + "\r\n";

                if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, rxHeader);
                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, textBox8.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, textBox8.Text);
                    textBox8.Clear();
                }

            }
            MessageBox.Show("Export  of " + comboBox5.Text + " table is complete!");
        }
    }
```

As you can see this is the path:

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\Jevon\\Desktop\\" + comboBox5.Text + ".csv";
```

How do I modify it so it can be the default export location for any computer the application is deployed on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), string.format("{0}.csv", comboBox5.Text));
```